# How to disable backlog (no waiting Connections)?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have a server which is supposed to open a `ServerSocket` connection to every client. The problem is, I need the clients to check if the ConnectionPort is in use already.
That means the Clients should check port 12345 and get a result if there is a `ServerSocket` "waiting" or not, and if not they take the next etc.

So in the end two or three clients are connected to the Server on port 12345, 12346, 12347...

I wrote this:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(incomingPort, 1); // backlog 1 = Minimum
incomingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
readerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingSocket.getInputStream()));

outgoingSocket = new Socket(incomingSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), outgoingPort);
dataOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outgoingSocket.getOutputStream());
pwOut = new OutputStreamWriter(outgoingSocket.getOutputStream());
```

I get the first client connected and open (in the last three lines) another connection "back" to the client. On the client side I wrote almost the same, the other way around:

```
outgoingSocket = new Socket(serverIP, inPort1);
dataOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outgoingSocket.getOutputStream());
pwOut = new OutputStreamWriter(outgoingSocket.getOutputStream());

serverSocket = new ServerSocket(outPort1);
incomingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
readerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingSocket.getInputStream()));
```

The next client that tries to open a connection is doing the same, starting with the same port. I was hoping to get an `Exception` like a `ConnectException` or so, but nothing. I guess it is related to the *backlog* "buffer". It continues with everything and waits to become a `ServerSocket` but it waits forever. The server itself is already occupied with the first connection.

I read many posts but they all say that `outgoingSocket.isConnected()` is giving `true` and `.isClosed()` is giving `false`, at least until the timeout. Is there any way of determing that the server is already occupied? Or at least to "disable" the backlog so all incoming connections are refused?

Comment: Make sure you understand the client-server communication model first. There is no need to increment ports in the server. Many clients can be connected to the same port on the server.

Comment: I understand that they can connect to the same port at the Server. So you mean, I should use the same port for every client/server and just address them with the different IPs?

Comment: No, you just have different `incomingSocket`s for each connection. `serverSocket` remains the same. So you differentiate them by reading/writing from/to appropriate socket. Read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you understand concept of client-server communication and socket interface. You don't need to create a new socket to communicate from server to client, TCP connections are bidirectional and you can write to the same socket that you read from.

Please refer to the official documentation for the good [EXAMPLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) of client-server, or follow the full [TUTORIAL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

If you still want to proceed with your approach, where the server accepts only a single connection, you need to close `serverSocket` in server after accepting the connection. Communication will still be possible using your `incomingSocket` class.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your direct question - no, you cannot disable listening TCP socket backlog queue, even if it's set to `1` - that's the number of ***pending***, i.e. not yet `accept()`-ed by application, connection requests. What you can do there is `close()` that server socket once you accepted the first client connection.

Then the real stuff - why do you think you need two sockets like this? A single TCP connection is **full-duplex**, i.e. you can communicate both ways.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Server which is supposed to open a SocketServer Connection to
>   every client.

No you don't. There is no such thing as a 'SocketServer Connection', and a TCP server creates one `ServerSocket` and *accepts* connections from clients. It is the clients which open connections.

> The problem is, I need the Clients to check if the
>   ConnectionPort is in use already.

No you don't. All the clients connect to the same port number. The clients don't have to check anything.

> That means the Clients should check:
>   Port 12345 and get a result if there is a ServerSocket "waiting" or
>   not. If not they take the next etc

No it doesn't. The clients just connect to the listening port. Period. You have completely misunderstood the entire process.

I suggest you do some reading and have a look at some code samples, and start again.

Comment: Yes, I noticed already that my understanding of the matter is not the best. So thanks for all the hints. I'm doing my homework again. :-)